# How can I format the date in react?

Tags: reactjs

I find myself with the difficulty that I cannot format the date in react, the following code was written in VUE JS and it ran perfectly. I would like someone to help me understand this concept please. The code is the following :

```
import spanish from 'date-fns/locale/es';
import parseISO from 'date-fns/parseISO'
import axios from 'axios';

<ListItem
   style={styles.list}
   title={<Text>{info.item.name}</Text>}
   description={<Text style={styles.list}>{`${info.item.description}`}</Text>}
   date={<Text>{format((parseISO(info.item.date)), 'dd/MMMM/yy', {locale: spanish})} 
         </Text>}
   accessoryLeft={renderItemIcon}
    onPress={() => navigation.push('Validator', {data: info.item, email: email})}
    >
      
</ListItem>
```

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: add this -> import { format } from 'date-fns';

Comment: If I have it added, the error is not from the import

Comment: what is default date format you are getting in info.item.date

Comment: Is this my friend 2022-09-10T16:00:00-05:00

Comment: But if I remove the Spanish language now it gives me invalid time value

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from "react";
import spanish from "date-fns/locale/es";
import parseISO from "date-fns/parseISO";
import format from "date-fns/format";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
              {format((parseISO("2022-01-01T16:00:00-05:00")), "dd-MMMM-yyyy",{ locale: spanish })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my piece of code, and this is working totally fine
result 02-enero-2022

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work in my code.

Comment: can u prepare a little working code in fiddle or something

Comment: forgive me yesterday I couldn't answer anymore, your answer was fine, only the UI KITTEN component didn't render it because I needed to put it in its own property.